# duvida em array

Tags: c, array, c++

Meu programa precisa receber dois vetores,A e B. Nisso se define o conjunto

> **A** pikachu **B**

como o conjunto formado pelos elementos que aparecem em A ou em B. Além disso, tem o conjunto

> **A** chikorita **B**

como o conjunto formado pelos elementos que aparecem tanto em **A** quanto em **B**.

Mas o outpout ta saindo errado. Teria que ser por exemplo:

> **input**
>       3 4
>       4 6 2
>       3 5 7 9
>
> **output**
>       pikachu: {2,3,4,5,6,7,9}
>       chikorita: {}

ps: nao terminei o codigo, eu fiz somente a parte em que os dois vetores sao iguais, mas mesmo assim nao esta imprimindo corretamente, o que pode ser?

meu codigo:

```
#include <stdio.h>    
void levet(int x, long long int vetor[]){    
    int i;  
    for(i=0;i<x;i++)  
    {  
        scanf("%lld",&vetor[i]);  
    }  
}

void arrumarvet(long long int vetor[], int n){  
    int i,j,aux;  

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n-1;j++){
            if(vetor[j] > vetor[j+1]){
                aux=vetor[j];
                vetor[j]=vetor[j+1];
                vetor[j+1]=aux;
            }
        }
    }
}   

int main(){   
    int i,j,n,m,cont=0;  
    long long int vetA[10000], vetB[10000];  
    long long int vetaux[10000];  
    scanf("%d %d",&n, &m);  
    levet(n,vetA);  
    levet(m,vetB);  
    arrumarvet(vetA,n);  
    arrumarvet(vetB,m);  

    for(i=0;i<n; i++){
        for(j=0;j<m;j++){
            if(vetA[j]== vetB[j]){
                cont++;
            }
            else if(vetA[j] != vetB[j]){
            vetaux[j]=vetA[j];
            }
        }
    }

    if(cont== m){
        printf("pikachu: {");
        for(i=0;i<m;i++)
        {
            printf("%d,",vetA[i]);
        }
        printf("}\n");
        printf("chikorita: {");
        for(i=0;i<m;i++)
        {
            printf("%d,",vetA[i]);
        }
        printf("}\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Se eu percebi corretamente está a tentar implementar união e intereseção em conjuntos é isso ? Em que o pikachu seria união e o chikorita interseção ?

Comment: Isso, pikachu seria ele mais a chikorita. E chikorita seria somente se aparecesse nela propria e no pikachu

Answer (score 0):

uma forma facil de resolver seria primeiro ordenar os vetores de entradas, após isso seria bom voce eliminar numeros repetidos, apesar de que... se for de fato conjuntos, nao é possivel ter elementos repetidos.

Para a união bastaria voce colocar os elementos dos dois vetores em um vetor auxiliar e eliminar os elementos repetidos.

Para a intersecção talvez algo assim

```css
void interseccao(int vetA[],int vetB[], int vetR[]){
    int i =0, j= 0, k = 0;

    for (i = 0; i<strlen(vetA); i++){
        for (j = 0; j<strlen(vetB); j++){
            if (vetA[i] == vetB[j]){
               vetR[k] = vetA[i];
               k = k + 1;
               break; 
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Sendo o vetR[] o vetor resultante, a função strlen retorna o tamnho do vetor